# Designing a simple IMDB style database with OOP

Tags: java, sql, database

This is a general OOP type question but I’ll need to work out the solution in Java.

I have a group project this semsester where the goal is to create a database system that manages credits for TV content. The database will therefore contain cast and crew members names, productions, production companies etc.

We need to design a database that can cross-referance between tables (think imdb), so that, lets say, if you were to select a ”Person” object you would be able to get a referance to every production this person worked on and which role they had. Again, think imdb if that helps.

We feel pretty confident about doing this with different tables in an SQL database, but we’re not to implement at persistance layer until the 2. iteration.

Our instructor has said that we need to design our domain/business layer first, with objects and make the database ”follow suit”.

So my question is: How do we design objects and classes that cross referance each other in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You might imagine your database tables are person, film and crew_member. crew_member is your join table that links a given person with a given film.

The domain design in Java might be as follows.

```
class Person
{
    String name;
}

class Film
{
    String title;
}

class CrewMember
{
    Person person;
    Film film;
    String role;
}
```